# ftp server file size difference vs actual file size

Tags: ftp, protocol

I am connecting to an FTP server to download some gzipped files and I noticed something a bit disconcerting about the SIZE command and my google-fu has failed me.

```
ftp> size file0001.xml.gz
213 2524751

ftp> nlist -ltr
...
-rw-r--r--   1 anon  anons    2515727 Jan 30 00:00 file0001.xml.gz
...
```

The file sizes are different, (2524751 != 2515727), as you can see. Why?

I've briefly read the [RCF0959 FILE TRANSFER PROTOCOL (FTP)](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc0959.txt) and there's no mention of the SIZE command, which I later found out to be a non-standard addition to the protocol.

Here's the bit about byte size, for convenience, from the RFC:

> ```
>   byte size
>
>      There are two byte sizes of interest in FTP:  the logical byte
>      size of the file, and the transfer byte size used for the
>      transmission of the data.  The transfer byte size is always 8
>      bits.  The transfer byte size is not necessarily the byte size
>      in which data is to be stored in a system, nor the logical byte
>      size for interpretation of the structure of the data.
> ```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Mahmoud

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you switched ftp into `binary` mode? ftp might be calculating the size with line-endings changed?

2524751 / 2515727 * 255 = 255.91469384396638

So it looks like every 255 bytes in the original gained 0.9 bytes extra - just enough for a compressed file to have `\n` converted to `\r\n`.

Comment: Hey Douglas! Sorry for getting back to you so late. 
The problem was that type was indeed in ascii format, I was using it through python's ftplib.

When I forced a retrbinary for size (retrbinary("RETR SIZE")), it worked like expected.

Thanks!